# Passing two values from a form dropdown

Tags: html, forms

This should be so simple. Basically I want people to be able to select from a dropdown and I want to pass the value and the actual text as two separate items. So from below I want one value for the class price and one for the class title. As it is I can only get the actual "value."

```
<select name="class" id="class" value="">

    <option selected="selected" value="none">none</option>

    <option value="$75.00">KinderDrawing for Pre-K Thursday 10am (Mar 20 to Apr 24) </option>

    <option value="$75.00">KinderDrawing for Pre-K FULL Saturday 9:00am (Apr 5 to May 10) </option>

    <option value="$55.00">Toddler Art Tuesday 10am (Mar 18 to Apr 22)</option>

    <option value="$55.00">Toddler Art Saturday 10:30am (Apr 5 to May 10)</option>  

</select>
```

Comment: You can pass only _one_ value with a select option – if you need two values, then you will have to combine them into one, f.e. using a separator character that can definitively not be part of either one. Btw., I hope you don’t rely on these prices sever-side without any validation? Otherwise shopping in your system would be quite cheap if the user wants to :-)

Comment: I could go for a free KinderDraw class - what's your website? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jquery, in an on-change method for the `select`

```
$("#class").change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var text = selectedOption.text();
    var value = selectedOption.val();
});
```